# What is a pump failure on a computer?

Tags: fan, alert

So I have this computer at my work that was giving me an error "Alert! Hard Drive fan failure." Well, I replaced that fan and then when I was bringing that computer back up, I received the following message in the screenshot. It is a Dell Optiplex 755, about 4 years old. **What in the world is a pump failure and how do I fix it?**

[image]

Comment: just a guess, pump might be related to water cooling if it where such a system.. otherwise it's a fan problem

Comment: Just clear the warning.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A pump failure would be on a liquid cooled system. If you don't have that, then it is referring to a fan failure.

To remove this, enter the setup utility and clear the warnings. It states "previous" failure, so if you have replaced the defective part and there is no continued failure, you won't see the warning again.